# how to unit test aws lambda with SQS Event

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am implementing a AWS Lambda that gets triggered from SQS, and then do some other thing.
This is my current Handler:

how I can pass a fake SQSEvent to test my function?

```
public class Handler implements RequestHandler<SQSEvent, Void> {
    @Override
    public Void handleRequest(SQSEvent sqsEvent, Context context) {
        helper(sqsEvent.record);

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `aws-lambda-java-tests` helps to simplify java lambda testing. Please refer [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-java-libs/tree/master/aws-lambda-java-tests) for details.

For sample code, refer [Testing AWS Lambda functions written in Java](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/testing-aws-lambda-functions-written-in-java/) blog.

Comment: Err, what’s the advantage of using an entire module which expects you to provide event data via json files over just constructing a ‘fake’ SQSEvent with this same data and calling the handler with it?